# How to set CookieContainer to BackgroundTransferRequest object in WP?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using `BackgroundTransferRequest` and `BackgroundTransferService` for uploading some data. Is there anyway I can set the `CookieContainer` to the `TransferRequest`?