# BackgroundTransferRequest with ASP.NET WIF authentication, HttpOnly cookies

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, wif

We are reaching an ASP.NET web application with WCF from Windows Phone. We use WIF on the server, the users of the application get the FedAuth cookie when they authenticate themselves with a WCF request. Afterwards we use the same cookie for every subsequent request to keep the user authenticated on the phone.

These cookies are HttpOnly, so they are not accessible directly, but that is not a problem, since we can share a `CookieContainer` object with every WCF service client.

However, we need to use a `BackgroundTransferRequest` to download a file from the server, where we also need to authenticate the user with the FedAuth cookie. But we can not access the cookie directly from the `CoookieContainer`, and `BackgroundTransferRequest` does not seem to support using a `CookieContainer`, only adding the cookies directly to its headers.

So my question is, how can I use `BackgroundTransferRequest`, if I have to send to the server the HttpOnly FedAuth cookie given by WIF? I would NOT want to switch off HttpOnly, if there is any other solution.

(I have seen that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174709/how-to-set-cookiecontainer-to-backgroundtransferrequest-object-in-wp) specific question did not get any answers, which *might* mean  it is not possible to directly associate a `CookieContainer` with a `BackgroundTransferRequest`.)